# Is a default constructor responsible for initializing members to default values?

Tags: java, constructor, default-value, default-constructor

A default constructor initializes all instance and class members to its default value.

is above statement True or False?

Answer (score 5):

No. The default constructor does nothing other than call `super()`.

Instance fields are always initialized to their default values before any constructors are run (it isn't the constructor that does it).

And, of course, static fields ("class members") are not initialized by a constructor. That'd be silly.

Comment: Thanks,  again  diverting  to  some  other  issue,  about  the  default  constructor  the  JLS  says "If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body."  What  does  statement "primordial class Object" means?

Comment: @Gpar Please don't ask new questions in comments - you should ask a separate question for that.